# Create a vector from a specific sequence of intervals

Tags: r, vector, range, sequence, intervals

I have 20 intervals:

10 intervals from 1 to 250 of size 25:

```
[1.25] [26.50] [51.75] [76.100] [101.125] [126.150] ... [226.250]
```

10 intervals from 251 to 1000 of size 75:

```
[251,325] [326,400] [401,475] [476,550] [551,625] ... [926,1000]
```

I would like to create a vector composed of the first 5 elements of each interval like:

```
(1,2,3,5, 26,27,28,29,30, 51,52,53,54,55, 76,77,78,79,80, ...., 
251,252,253,254,255, 326,327,328,329,330, ...)
```

How create this vector using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have two interval like :

```
interval1 <- seq(1.25, 226.250, 25)
interval2 <- seq(251, 1000, 75)
```

We can create a new interval combining the two and then use `mapply` to create sequence

```
new_interval <- c(as.integer(interval1), interval2)
c(mapply(`:`, new_interval, new_interval + 4))
 #[1]   1   2   3   4   5  26  27  28  29  30  51  52  53  54 .....
 #[89] ..... 779 780 851 852 853 854 855 926 927 928 929 930
```